# dynamodb how to define none key schema in serverless.yml?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, serverless-framework, serverless

I try to apply a dynamodb in my serverless aws lambda.
My file is like:

```
resources:
  Resources:
    StoreDynamoDbTable:
      Type: 'AWS::DynamoDB::Table'
      DeletionPolicy: Retain
      Properties:
        AttributeDefinitions:
          - AttributeName: id
            AttributeType: S
          - AttributeName: lat
            AttributeType: N 
          - AttributeName: lng
            AttributeType: N
        KeySchema:
          - AttributeName: id
            KeyType: HASH
        ProvisionedThroughput:
          ReadCapacityUnits: 1
          WriteCapacityUnits: 1
        TableName: ${self:provider.environment.TableStore}
```

I try to apply lat and lng as attributes of storeTable, just the attribute not key Schema, but every store element should have these attributes.

But there is error:

> An error occurred: StoreDynamoDbTable - Property AttributeDefinitions
>   is inconsistent with the KeySchema of the table and the secondary
>   indexes.

How to make lat and lng just mast attribute,not key element for index?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

DynamoDB requires that you declare ONLY the attributes that compose your key schema. ([See AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_en/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-dynamodb-attributedef.html))

If `id` is the only attribute that is used to compose your key schema, your resource should look like this:

```
resources:
  Resources:
    StoreDynamoDbTable:
      Type: 'AWS::DynamoDB::Table'
      DeletionPolicy: Retain
      Properties:
        AttributeDefinitions:
          - AttributeName: id
            AttributeType: S
        KeySchema:
          - AttributeName: id
            KeyType: HASH
        ProvisionedThroughput:
          ReadCapacityUnits: 1
          WriteCapacityUnits: 1
        TableName: ${self:provider.environment.TableStore}
```

DynamoDB doesn't care about the other attributes. Upon inserting your data, DynamoDB will detect the new attributes without having to declare them in a schema. That's the whole point of a non-relational database.

---

Additionally, if you wanted to have a date as sort key in your key schema, you could have something like this:

```
resources:
  Resources:
    StoreDynamoDbTable:
      Type: 'AWS::DynamoDB::Table'
      DeletionPolicy: Retain
      Properties:
        AttributeDefinitions:
          - AttributeName: id
            AttributeType: S
          - AttributeName: date
            AttributeType: S
        KeySchema:
          - AttributeName: id
            KeyType: HASH
          - AttributeName: date
            KeyType: RANGE
        ProvisionedThroughput:
          ReadCapacityUnits: 1
          WriteCapacityUnits: 1
        TableName: ${self:provider.environment.TableStore}
```

A key schema always have at least a partition (`HASH`) key and can optionally have a sort (`RANGE`) key. [Check this to learn more about DynamoDB's key schema.](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/choosing-the-right-dynamodb-partition-key/)